# From controller display a popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement linked-in Authentication. When I setup a debug point at `var response` I see a HTML code that is the Authentication window of linked-In.

Now, How can I use that code and popup the Linked-In authentication window using that code ?

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetResponseString()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();



        var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile");


        return View("Index");
    }
```

Documentation for [Linkedin authentication](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2)

Comment: What stop you to make same call from the client - javascript?

Comment: Go for OWIN based OAuth implementation - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874207/LinkedIn-Authentication-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: There are several examples already on this site that do precisely what you are looking to do. Simply search for "writing content to popup window from asp .net".

Comment: @Developer I think OWIN will not work Linked-in has released a new API. Am I correct ?

Comment: Is that so?? Could you please check this - https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services#TWITTER & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.twitterauthenticationextensions.usetwitterauthentication(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: A pop up is a client-side thing. The server cannot control that. When you see OAuth popups on other websites, those are using the JavaScript OAuth APIs.